# Swift3 エラー　Argument labels '(string:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: swift3, macos

このエラーがわかりません。

```
    func xml_parse( html: String){
    if let doc = try? XMLDocument(string: html) {
        if let root = doc.root {
            let rss = root.xpath("/rss//item/*")
            NSLog("Item: \(rss.count)")

            // iterate through all children
            var title = ""

            for element in rss{
                if(element.tag == "title") {
                    title = element.stringValue
                } else if (element.tag == "link"){
                    self.add_item(title: title, link: element.stringValue)
                }
                NSLog("Elements \(element.tag): \(element.attributes)")
            }

            NSLog("\(self.items)")
            if (self.delegate != nil) {
                self.delegate!.notify(rssThread: self)
            }
        }

    }
```

上から３行目[XMLDocument(string: html) {]
のXにした線がついており、エラーが出ます。→Argument labels '(string:)' do not match any available overloads

何を変えればいいのでしょうか？

Comment: Mac(あるいはLinux?)用のコードでしょうか? ご質問を書く際にはそこら辺をタグ等で明示していただけるようお願いします。MacやLinux用のコードでシステム標準(Foundationフレームワーク)の`XMLDocument`を使っておられるのか、iOS等他のプラットフォームでサードパーティ製の`XMLDocument`を使っておられるのかで回答できる内容が変わってきます。

Comment: Mac用のコードです。

Comment: 特にサードパーティ製のフレームワークをご使用になっていると言う意識はないと言うことで良いでしょうか?